# replace string (variables) php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this: `foo($bar1, $bar2)`

How to I replace each variable with `<span>$variable</span>` with regexp?

This is my try (not working):

```
$row['name'] = preg_replace("/\$\w+/S", "<span>$1</span>", $row['name']);
```

I only want the variables to be replaced and have a `span` around them, I don't want commas or spaces to be replaced.

What I want is to have my string `foo($bar1, $bar2)` to be replaced with `foo(<span>$bar1</span>, <span>$bar2</span>)` ($bar1 and $bar2 are not variables, it's plain text).

Comment: The "before / after" example is unclear. Can you show a full example?

Comment: @Marwelin What results do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems I can see:

- Since you are using double quotes for the regex,
  you need to escape the `$` using two `\` as `\\$`.
  Alternatively you can just use single
  quote and use `\$`.
- You are using `$1` in the replacement
  but you are not having any group in
  the regex. So have `(  )` around
  `\$\w+`

So try:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\$\w+)/', "<span>$1</span>", $str);
```

or

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\\$\w+)/", "<span>$1</span>", $str);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/SEiWr).